# Why could curl and wget timeout every now and then

Tags: travis-ci

Every now and then (<5%) Travis builds stall because `wget` calling a PHP page times out. Example: https://travis-ci.org/marcelstoer/nodemcu-custom-build/builds/69239694 I was using `curl` first for several weeks but then tried `wget` because of this issue.

**cURL**

```
curl -m 60 url
```

**wget**

```
wget -qO- url &> /dev/null
```

The server which serves the PHP page doesn't report any errors and in the Apache access log the request to the PHP page is reported as returning HTTP 200.

What could I do to further analyze?

Comment: I had a look at your `.travis.yml` file and a suggestion I have is to remove the pipe to `&> /dev/null` for the misbehaving `wget` call and see if it outputs any error. You could also add the following switches `--debug --verbose` to `wget`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try even though when I was still using `curl` I didn't send the output to `/dev/null` yet still never saw any error at all.

Comment: Update: ever since I added `--debug --verbose` more than a week ago the `wget` command never timed out. Weird but ok...